# get-content in .ldif file wiht powershell

Tags: powershell

Recently i had to search and export entried from an ldif file.
I used to do it manually but i'm trying to script it:

here is the code:

```
write-host "my entry"

$uid = read-host "entry's uid:"

$attribute = (get-adobject -server "***.***.***.***:***" -LDAPFilter "(cn=$uid)" -SearchBase 'dc=my,dc=domain' -properties *).myattribute

get-content -path "D:\myfile.ldif" |select-string -pattern "$attribute"
```

For some reason using the  `$attribute` does not work, yet making the same research manually work perfectly as long as i enter the string not as a variable.

i managed to separate the entries using :

```
$1= get-content "myfile.ldif" |out-string
$2= [system.Environment]::Newline
$3= ($1 -split "$2$2")
```

now i'm stuck making the research.

If someone has an idea

Answer (score 0):

turn out my get-adobject was the problem, just had to change `$mydata` to `$mydata[0]`

```
(get-content -raw -path "D:\my\file.ldif") -split '\r?\n\r?\n' -match $mydata[0]
```